# How to know what line of code executed an Entity Framework dynamic SQL statement without using Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

One of the benefits of using stored procedures for data access, whether using Entity Framework (EF)  or not, and in very large projects is the ability to capture the stored proc names in the SQL Server Profiler and doing a global search for the proc name and finding quickly in the code where the statement was executed.

However when using EF and dynamic SQL (from using Linq), the SQL statement can't be searched because they are created during run time by EF.

Let's say some SQL statements were captured in the profiler from a production server, what's a good way or trick to find out where in the code these statements were created? (Remote debugging is not an option. Attaching to production databases from VS is not an option. Enabling EF's logging from within the code is not implemented)

Comment: This probably won't help you directly, but as an idea - here's a little something we do in our dapper/mini-profiler build: we inject the path and line number into the TSQL using the new C# caller-member-info attributes; here's an example from this very page load: `select /* Models\Post.Answers.cs@32 */` - line 32 of Models\Post.Answers.cs, available in one click via mini-profiler. Very handy, but I can't think of a way to inject it into EF without major work

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't recommend it, but you could do nasty stuff like:

```
.where(1 == 1)  //Get Contacts in some method A
.ToList();
```

then in another area you could

```
.where(2 == 2)  //Get Contacts in some method B
.ToList();
```

I'm pretty sure this wouldn't get compiled out, and has no (major) affect on the SQL generated, but it is extremely hacky.  You should be able to see in Profiler the same where statements.